Local Git Repository is locked after pulling from fork
I tried for the first time to pull the Unreal Engine 5 repository from github (specifically the ue5-main branch which is the "dev" branch). I made a local branch of it called katianie-ue5-main but whenever I try to build the project, I'm getting errors in Visual Studio saying access denied to all the files. It looks like all the files are set to read only in windows explorer.
Is there a way to unlock the folders or is there the concept of checkout with Git Desktop?
I tried manually un-ticking read only on the locked folders but that does not work.
Here is what my Git Desktop looks like:

And the Repository in Windows Explorer is locked as seen here:

Git Status:
Refresh index: 100% (178229/178229), done.
On branch katianie-ue5-main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/katianie-ue5-main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
deleted:    Engine/Binaries/Linux/UnrealBuildAccelerator/.dockerignore
deleted:    Engine/Binaries/Linux/UnrealBuildAccelerator/Dockerfile
deleted:    Engine/Extras/VirtualProduction/FlutterLiveLinkVCAM/assets/eula.html
deleted:    Engine/Source/ThirdParty/ShaderConductor/ShaderConductor/External/DirectXShaderCompiler/utils/git/code-format-helper.py
deleted:    Engine/Source/ThirdParty/ShaderConductor/ShaderConductor/External/DirectXShaderCompiler/utils/git/code-format-save-diff.py
deleted:    Engine/Source/ThirdParty/ShaderConductor/ShaderConductor/External/DirectXShaderCompiler/utils/git/requirements_formatting.txt

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.Tests/
Engine/Source/Programs/AutomationTool.Tests/bin/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

git branch -av
* katianie-ue5-main                           ca4d8114db32 [PCG] Add warning when trying to import an alembic file with no point cloud data or no points.
  release                                     16dc333db3d6 5.4.1 release
  ue5-main                                    ca4d8114db32 [PCG] Add warning when trying to import an alembic file with no point cloud data or no points.
  remotes/origin/4.0                          dd065b230564 Engine source for 4.0.2 (4.0 branch up to CL 2034640)
  remotes/origin/4.1                          9b460da0ad7f Code snapshot for CL 2061508
  remotes/origin/4.10                         82c6eea53830 Rebuilt binaries for promoted changelist 2872498.
  remotes/origin/4.11                         c0df86062ad4 Back-port fix for mismatched argument errors compiling precompiled headers in VS2015 update 3.
  remotes/origin/4.12                         fd7794c48b37 Updating path for Rocket builds in 4.12 branch in case we do another hotfix release.
  remotes/origin/4.13                         aaf118e0c108 fix for FramePacer on iOS #rb none #lockdown nick.penwarden #jira UE-37704
  remotes/origin/4.14                         6957dd274b94 [Localization Update] Project: Engine Target: Keywords
  remotes/origin/4.15                         12d23e7ac4c2 Branch snapshot for CL 3451409
  remotes/origin/4.16                         37ca478f5aa3 Localization Automation
  remotes/origin/4.17                         db813ce277df Localization Automation
  remotes/origin/4.18                         de25f76316ed Copy xbox one mip corruption fix from dev-console CLs 3801550 and 3768615.
  remotes/origin/4.19                         ea87f4fb26ff License Check-in for WebCamAndVideo
  remotes/origin/4.2                          4225a79ca5ea Updated README.MD for 4.2.1 release
  remotes/origin/4.20                         5c73d9fb0afb Localization Automation
  remotes/origin/4.21                         7acbae1c8d17 Branch snapshot for CL 4972232
  remotes/origin/4.22                         8fb368305d69 Localization Automation
  remotes/origin/4.23                         87f8792983fb Localization Automation
  remotes/origin/4.24                         5502af308632 Branch snapshot for CL 11596182
  remotes/origin/4.25                         cede3321b23e Branch snapshot for CL 14826844
  remotes/origin/4.25-plus                    2d1aaeede678 Branch snapshot for CL 16138940


Your second screenshot looks like it's an issue with windows file permissions in general, not necessarily to do with git. Have you tried removing the "read only" checkbox, or something like this Q&A?

Yes, I tried manually un-ticking read only on the locked folders but that does not work. It simply stays read only.

Perhaps also show git status and git branch -av.

@Christoph sounds good, I added those to the original post.

You are aware of deleted and untracked files? Maybe this is (part of) the problem? I would guess, your question is not about Git but about your library ("how to install..."). If I were you, I would ask a new question and close this one. Disclaimer: I have no idea what your cloned library does nor how it works. However, your Git output looks fine.

I was able to fix the issue, I think the problem was that I put the UnrealEngine folder in Program Files. In addition to this, I changed the User permission settings in the advanced section. Here is how to fix:

Delete the repo and put it in a location not in Program Files or somewhere protected. I went with just "D:\LocalUnrealEngine" for location.
Right click the folder, go to properties, then security, and click Advanced.
At the top of the window, you will see "Owner", click change to the right of it.
In the box that says "Enter the object name", Type in "Users" and click "Check Names".
Click OK, then in the window, tick the box that says "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" Also tick the box that says "Replace All child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" and click apply then OK.
On the original window for properties, un-tick "read only" and click apply then OK.

I was able to build the UE5.sln after this.
